# Why does this give an unchecked cast warning?

Tags: java, generics

Consider this example:

```
interface A<T> {}
interface B<T> extends A<T> {
    void run();
}
class Test {
    public void main(String[] args) {
        A<SomeType> a = ...;
        if (a instanceof B)
            ((B<SomeType>) a)    //warning: "Type safety: unchecked cast"
                .run();
    }
}
```

Why does that give an unchecked cast warning? Is there a way this cast could be dangerous, or can I simply ignore this warning?

Note, that I can't use `if (a instanceof B<SomeType>)`, because that gives the following compiler error:

> Cannot perform instanceof check against parameterized type B<SomeType>. Use the form B<?> instead since further generic type information will be erased at runtime

And, if I use `if (a instanceof B<?>)`, that still gives the same warning.

Comment: I don't see a warning. Can you post your actual code?

Comment: At any rate, the fact that a is an instance of B does not say anything about the nature of the generic type parameter. Due to type erasure that cannot be guaranteed.

Comment: @Sotirios Nevermind, it was a derp.

Comment: @Edwin But it must be an instance of `B<SomeType>` if `B<T> extends A<T>`.

Comment: Voting to close (typographical error).

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: (Comment here rather than on my now-deleted answer.) Looks like my answer makes sense for the *actual* code, but I agree it doesn't make as much sense for the *posted* code ;)

Comment: @JonSkeet I wouldn't have deleted it. Just update. It's still very useful, especially if you explain the raw type implications.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: Okay, will do.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: See whether my update covers all the relevant bases. Happy to keep improving :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I derped.

I wrote:

```
interface B<T> extends A {
```

instead of:

```
interface B<T> extends A<T> {
```

Answer (score 4):

When this happens normally, it means that the cast isn't *really* checking anything. Here's a concrete example:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        List<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();
        strings.add("Foo");

        Object o = strings;
        if (o instanceof List) {
            List<Integer> integers = (List<Integer>) o;
            System.out.println("The cast 'worked'");
            Integer firstInteger = integers.get(0); // ClassCastException
        }
    }
}
```

At execution time, there's no such thing as a `List<Integer>` - there's just a `List` which happens to contain `Integer` references, and a `List` which happens to contain `String` references, etc. So the only execution-time check a cast to `List<Integer>` performs is that it really *is* a `List`.

In your actual code, you had:

```
interface B<T> extends A { ... }
```

That's using the *raw type*... which means that just because you've got a reference to an `A<Foo>` which is also a `B`, it doesn't need to really be a `B<Foo>`. When you're using raw types, all kinds of bets are off :)

In the code you posted, with:

```
interface B<T> extends A<T> { ... }
```

you *don't* have a warning, because if you've *genuinely* got an `A<Foo>` which is a `B`, it must be a `B<Foo>`. (Of course, you could only have an `A<Foo>` via another unsafe cast, but that means the problem occurs earlier on.)

See the [Java Generics FAQ on type erasure](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TechnicalDetails.html#Type%20Erasure) and on [raw types](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/ParameterizedTypes.html#Raw%20Types) for more details.

Comment: I pre+1'ed you because I wouldn't expect any less. Now I have a raw type headache :(

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: If it's any consolation, raw types make my head hurt too. The way *all* generics go when you use the raw type (not just the ones using the type parameter) is always surprising...